# Error when running rescale in R causing unused arguments

Tags: r, image, imagemagick

I'm running the code in this example

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/01/extracting-colours-from-your-images-with-image-quantization/#google_vignette

I constantly get this error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `hex = hsv(rescale(c.1, from = c(0, 360)), c.2, c.3)`.
Caused by error in `rescale()`:
! unused argument (from = c(0, 360))

I know the error happens inside this function:

```
get_colorPal <- function(im, n=8, cs="RGB"){
  #print(cs) 
  tmp <-im %>% image_resize("100") %>% 
    image_quantize(max=n, colorspace=cs) %>%  ## reducing colours! different colorspace gives you different result
    magick2cimg() %>%  ## I'm converting, becauase I want to use as.data.frame function in imager package.
    RGBtoHSV() %>% ## i like sorting colour by hue rather than RGB (red green blue)
    as.data.frame(wide="c") %>%  #3 making it wide makes it easier to output hex colour
    mutate(hex=hsv(rescale(c.1, from=c(0,360)),c.2,c.3),
           hue = c.1,
           sat = c.2,
           value = c.3) %>%
    count(hex, hue, sat,value, sort=T) %>% 
    mutate(colorspace = cs)

  return(tmp %>% select(colorspace,hex,hue,sat,value,n)) ## I want data frame as a    result.

}

## Here's example using plum flower image 
get_colorPal(im)
```

I can get it to work by randomly uninstalling and reinstalling packages plyr and dplyr, I think some base function maybe getting over written? This custom function does exactly what I need, but it will not work every time/consistently, I have no clue why?
Any help would be great.

Paul.

Comment: Explicitily call functions that are being hidden due to the order of loading of packages i.e. `dplyr::mutate(...)` and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the response, that didn't change anything still getting the same error?

Comment: Then perhaps the function used is not from the package you think it is used. Or perhaps code depends on some older version of the package given that the post is from 2019.

Comment: I resolved the issue by using scales::rescale thanks